# What are some "must have" iPhone/iTouch apps for IT people?

Tags: iphone, apple

I just got my iPhone, and am on an app-downloading spree.  Help me build my list of apps!

I'm marking this question as fun so that we can also include apps that aren't necessarily useful for IT people, but that IT people might enjoy.  However, if it is more of a "fun" app, please mark your answer community wiki.

Also, here's the [comparable question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567204/best-iphone-apps-for-a-developer).

Comment: "What is the best cereal... for IT people..."

Comment: Notice that I didn't ask which one is the "best." :-)  I was just wondering what useful Apps people might know about.

Comment: @Zifre - I disagree.  Some of the answers genuinely are useful for IT staff, and if I mark it CW all answers have to be CW.

Comment: What are some "must have" cereals for IT people

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Collecting into one big answer:

- Citrix Client
- Air Sharing (use it like a network-attached thumbdrive)
- Skype (to keep in contact with your other clients)
- [iStat](http://bjango.com/apps/istat/) for monitoring Max OS X.
- [Slicehost Pro](http://www.slicehost.com/articles/2009/4/27/slicehost-iphone-app-now-free).
- [Analytics](http://analyticsapp.com/) for Google Analytics.
- TouchTerm (SSH client)
- SSH Client (iSSH)
- Mylite (for looking inside servers when you have no torch!)
- Snap: network scan (ports, services)
- Network Ping Lite: discover and ping IP addresses
- Remote Desktop Lite: Remote Desktop
- sSubNet: subnet mask calculator
- WinAdmin: Windows Remote Desktop

Comment: You might want to make this community wiki since it was contributed to by everyone.

Comment: You're right - in fact, I thought I had when I posted it.

Answer (score 7):

Cydia (lets you add loads more apps)

Comment: It's helpful to note this is what you get when you jailbreak you iPhone, which not everyone wants to do.

Comment: Agreed, should have made this clearer. That said I have no idea why my response has been voted down twice, jailbreaking isn't like clubbing seals.

Comment: What apps that it enables are useful though?

Comment: SBSettings in particular, plus you can get Intelliscreen which I like too.

Answer (score 7):

I have a **dedicated page** on my iPhone with useful applications:

[image]

- Jaadu RDP: the best Remote Desktop Client (RDP) for the iPhone I found. It's a very intuitive and powerful app.
- Snap: network scan (ports, services)
- Network Ping Lite: discover and ping IP addresses
- WiFiFiFom: detect and visualize wireless networks
- aSubNet: subnet mask calculator for IP addresses
- Remote Desktop Lite: RD to XP machines
- Whois: the name says it all
- Domain Scout: shows the availability of domain names
- Speed Test: two nice apps, the second one is Cisco's
- Analytics: nice app for checking your Google Analytics accounts and sites
- iTap: remote control your PC or Mac using the iPhone's touchpad
- Bookmarks: all my Delicious bookmarks
- Skype: cheap calls whereever I am
- Soonr: access by backed up documents from everywhere
- iFirstAid: you'll never know what happens in the server room

Other apps not on the same page:

- iSSH (SSH Console)

Comment: Couldn't find WiFiFiFom in the Apple store :(

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few I have on my device:

- If you're monitoring Mac OS X machines, I've found that [iStat](http://bjango.com/apps/istat/) is very useful. It also has ping and traceroute built in to do some basic network diagnostics.
- If you're a Slicehost user, the now-free [Slicehost Pro](http://www.slicehost.com/articles/2009/4/27/slicehost-iphone-app-now-free) is a great way to monitor your slices.
- If you use Google Analytics, the [Analytics](http://analyticsapp.com/) app is great to quickly check basic stats for your site.

Answer (score 4):

TouchTerm (SSH client)

Answer (score 3):

- Remote Desktop App (RDP)
- SSH Client (iSSH)
- Mylite (for looking inside servers when you have no torch!)

Answer (score 3):

I'll add to those:

- Air Sharing (use it like a network-attached thumbdrive)
- Skype (to keep in contact with your *other* clients)

Answer (score 2):

Mocha VNC Lite is good.

However i did find even if the host is set to 800x600 my iPhone complains it is running low on memory... turning off 32-bit colour mode in the client seems to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

[iStat for iPhone](http://bjango.com/apps/istat/) is good for checking system stats.

Answer (score 1):

My website is hosted with slicehost, so the Slicehost tool is excellent for starting, stopping my server, changing DNS settings and all sorts of other admin stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Apple servers then Harlekins [Server Admin Remote](http://harlekins.org/ServerAdminRemote/Server_Admin_Remote.html) is handy. It lets you check server status, and start/stop services.

Answer (score 1):

[NetPortal](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netportal-access-files-on/id323133602?mt=8) let's you browse file shares. I use it in combination with VPN to browse Windows shares at the office

Answer (score 0):

webadmin is a really neat rdp client

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to recommend [Thinstuff iRDesktop](http://www.irdesktop.com/). It's free and seems to work far better than the free mocha RDP.

It can have multiple simultaneous RDP connections. It uses safari-like page switching, and supports right click(which the mocha one doesn't support). I've just tested it in the office and it's really quick. We'll see how it fairs over the VPN from home tonight.

[Check out iRDesktop on iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=311467740&mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

I've been very happy with [wifi analyzer](http://appadvice.com/app/337359041).  $2, but well worth it.

Comment: Looks like this has been removed from the app store since posting.

Answer (score 0):

[iPowerShell](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ipowershell/id306602044?mt=8#) is nice, if you are a powershell user.

Answer (score 0):

- TeamViewer
- Dropbox
- Firefox Home

Those are still missing from the list :)

TeamViewer is a VNC-like app that works quite well even over slow EDGE connections and doesn't require any kind of Portforwarding.

Dropbox is, well, a portable app where you can access all parts and data of your Dropbox, just as you would from PC/Mac or the web.

Firefox Home lets you access all of your bookmarks, open tabs and history of Firefox on your computer, it however needs a plugin installed there.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a play with [Servercontrol](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/servercontrol-reboot-manage/id353030464?mt=8) and I'm liking it.

For £2.99, you get a nice gui for stop/starting services, rebooting/shutting down and a file manager.

Answer (score 0):

[TeamViewer Mobile](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/teamviewer/id357069581?mt=8) with TeamViewer Quick Support (http://www.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerQS.exe) is the best combination for remote support I have found so far. Wherever you are, just point the person needed of support to download the windows client, run it without installation and instantly connect to it with your mobile phone.