# Can a network drive be mapped to an iPhone?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iphone

I know that a Cisco VPN profile can be setup on iPhones. If I was able to get that setup on the phone, would it be possible to map a network drive to the iPhone?

Would want to map it to a folder on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The app NetPortal can do this. I've got it set on my non-jail broken phone. I connect the native VPN to the office network and I can browse the network. You don't map a drive just have "favourites" in the application and then open them up.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netportal-access-files-on/id323133602?mt=8

Comment: +1, Interesting app, I'll have to check it out. You may consider adding it to [the CW of syadmin iOS apps](http://serverfault.com/questions/2423/what-are-some-must-have-iphone-itouch-apps-for-it-people).

Comment: This looks like it should meet my needs, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically yes, iphones are just very locked-down BSD-like machines, when I was messing about with jail-breaking mine I found it very easy to get SSH working at which point it would be possible to install all manner of fairly standard *nix code, including a SAMBA client and any other tools. It'll take you a fair bit of faffing about and obviously you do this at your own disk but I think it's eminently possible yes.

I do have to ask the question why?

Comment: The CEO of our company would like to be able to access his network drives using his iPhone.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but why does he want to do this? what does he think he'll be able to do then? Have you come across the 'Dropbox' application? might be easier

Comment: "what does he think he'll be able to do then" open and read documents...

Comment: But you'd have to be very specific about how and where you put the files if you used a samba client in order for them to be readable by an iphone due to the app-specific storage mechanisms apple use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is - not as Apple ship it anyway - aside from anything else, the iphone doesn't make file systems available to the end user.